# How to transfer data on SQL Table to Excel file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

So I have a working piece of code which creates and modifies data in a SQL table. I now want to transfer all the data in the SQL table to a Excel file. Which libraries would I use and what functions in those libraries would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an example of database with sqlite: memory.db
and table name is called table1 in the example

```
import os
import csv
import sqlite3

def db2csv(file,Table1):
    con = sqlite3.connect("memory.db")
    cur = con.cursor()

    if not os.path.exists(file):
        os.makedirs(file)

    with open(file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1 '):
            spamwriter.writerow(row)
    con.commit()
```

Comment: So would the variable "file" be the name of the SQL file?

Comment: yes, and you can call the function db2csv() in your code